# Using TREATAS to get Measure from Another Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm back with another issue. I have a sales table with transaction details on the products purchased. I also have a table with warehouse inventory information for each product. I'm trying to get the count of products purchased in a Table visualization with columns from the warehouse inventory table.

I tried both of the measures below, but they both return the total Count for each row rather than sliced by product. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
NumProductsfromSales1 = calculate([Count], treatas(values('Sales'[Product]), 'Inventory'[Product]))

NumProductsfromSales2 = 
var lineage = treatas(values('Sales'[Product]), 'Inventory'[Product])
var tbl = calculatetable('Inventory Detail', KEEPFILTERS(lineage))
var result = calculate(sumx(tbl, [Count]))
return  result
```

Comment: How is `[Count]` defined?

Comment: Count is a measure defined as the sum of product count for each transaction within a certain distance. I guess it makes sense it wouldn't work because of the distance filter. I'm not sure how to get around that though. 

"""[Count] = calculate(sum('Sales'[Product Count]) , filter('Sales', [Sales Distance] < [Mile Input]))"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this source](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/), we see `TREATAS` works as follows.

```
[Filtered Measure] :=
CALCULATE (
    <target_measure>,
    TREATAS (
        VALUES ( <lookup_granularity_column> ),
        <target_granularity_column>
    )
)
```

is equivalent to

```
[Filtered Measure] :=
CALCULATE (
    <target_measure>,
    INTERSECT (
        ALL ( <target_granularity_column> ),
        VALUES ( <lookup_granularity_column> )
    )
)
```

The important part is the `ALL` function. That's why you're losing the filter context from the rows in the visual.

---

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but I think if you add `Inventory` as a filter table to your first attempt, it should maintain the filter context on that table from the row in the visual.

```
NumProductsfromSales1 =
CALCULATE (
    [Count],
    'Inventory',
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Sales'[Product] ), 'Inventory'[Product] )
)
```

---

**Edit:** Regarding your comment, try the following:

```
a =
VAR top5prod =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        TOPN (
            5,
            SUMMARIZE ( Sales, Sales[Product], "Count", [Product Count] ),
            [Count]
        ),
        "Product", Sales[Product]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Product Count],
        FILTER ( 'Inventory', 'Inventory'[Product] IN top5prod )
    )
```

Using `FILTER` isn't as efficient as `TREATAS` but see if it works.

It's very difficult to answer this sort of question without having anything reproducible to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are all giving me the total count. Is there a way to use a table variable to get the count?  (I'm actually trying to get count for the top 5 products again, but tried to simplify the question above). 


 `   var top5prod = SELECTCOLUMNS(
        TOPN(
            5 SUMMARIZE(Sales, Sales[Product], "Count", [Product Count]),
             [Count]), 
            "Product", Sales[Product])

    return CALCULATE([Product Count], TREATAS(top5prod, Inventory'[Product]))`

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure if the question is answerable with the detail given though.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just got it to work by switching the order of the TREATAS! Inventory had to go first and then Sales.